# grep: What is the limit for a pattern file size

Tags: grep, files, input, limit, size

I am using `grep` with the `-f` option and I run into an issue when the pattern file given with `-f` is very long. The one that is failing for me has almost 300 thousand lines and 40 MBytes. `grep` does not refuse to run but ends `Killed`. Is there a specific maximum size for the pattern file?

Comment: If your patterns are strings (not regex) you could try to add `-F` switch. Otherwise, is something written to syslog (memory exhausted maybe)?

Comment: Both good tips, though `-F` does not help in my case. It could, however, fix some borderline cases. Syslog says `Out of memory: Killed process 2965427 (grep) total-vm:1897916kB, anon-rss:1879488kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:3736kB oom_score_adj:0` That would suggest that the limit will depend on memory, although 40 Megs of the original file does not seem that much.

Comment: I'd speculate that you're reaching some memory quota for the user you're running the command as.  Could try running it with `sudo` (if you have sufficient privs) to see how they behaves.  Don't really understand your use case from the description given, but 300k patterns seems a lot (and obviously causing you a problem).  What if break it down into multiple files?  You would have to process the input multiple times though.

Comment: `sudo` does not change the behaviour, `grep` gets killed just the same. I hit this issue by chance. I have a `cron` jobs that makes a list of new files that have appeared in a datastore, and then removes some based on a previously stored list. Normally it works, but I today I started the script with empty history, so the list of files to remove grew exceptionally big. I can avoid that condition, and I could certainly split the pattern file. Frankly I was just curious how large the chunks could be to be safe :-)